# Ajax not receiving data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache

I'm attempting to stream php data to an ajax handler and display it on the page using the code below, but on some devices the results being echoed by the page are't being displayed. I've used wireshark to confirm that the data is being received by the host (can see it in the tcp packets) but it doesn't seem to make it to ajax? What could possibly be going wrong?

Client side:

```
$.ajax( 
    {
        xhrFields: {
            onprogress: function(e)
            {
                var this_response, response = e.currentTarget.response;

                if(last_response_len === false)
                {
                        this_response = response;
                        last_response_len = response.length;
                }
                else
                {
                        this_response = response.substring(last_response_len);
                        last_response_len = response.length;
                }

                /* Put output on page */
                $('#tool-output-area').append(this_response + '<br>');

            }
        },
  method: 'POST',
    url: '../../../../../../../../page.php',
    data:
  { 
    data-key: data-variable...
  }
    })
    .done(function(data)
    {
      // stuff
    })
    .fail(function()
    {
        // stuff
    });
});
```

Server Side:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

/* Set Maximum Execution Time By Plan */
ini_set('max_execution_time', getMaxExeTime());

ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);

ob_implicit_flush(true);

while (ob_get_level() > 0) 
{
  $level = ob_get_level();
  ob_end_clean();
  if (ob_get_level() == $level) break;
}

if (function_exists('apache_setenv')) 
{
  apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
  apache_setenv('dont-vary', '1');
}

// Checks

$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
    1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
    2 => array("file", "proc.txt", "a")
);

$pipes = array();
$process = proc_open('exec ' . escapeshellcmd($tool_command), $descriptorspec, $pipes, '/path-here', null);
$proc_details = proc_get_status($process);
$pid = $proc_details['pid'];

$proc_row = logProcess($pid, $tool_command, $output_file, $tool);

$str = '';

session_write_close();

if(is_resource($process)) 
{
    while ($curStr = fgets($pipes[1])) 
    {
        echo nl2br(htmlentities($curStr)); // Send the data back
        flush();
        $str .= nl2br(htmlentities($curStr));
        $arr = proc_get_status($process);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

fclose($pipes[0]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
proc_close($process);
```